# revert photo upload process instead of delete from folder manually

Tags: php

I use html5 file api so the flow is more direct and better UX in my opinion. When the user select their image, there will be a preview and the upload is running in backend in the same time. What I want to add is a cancel button.

Just curious is there any shortcut to undo or revert the last action (upload)?? or I need to manually write the delete logic?

Answer (score 0):

You would simply just delete the uploaded file using [unlink()](https://www.php.net/unlink) and remove from database if necessary.